# R: Error in .Primitive, non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I did some reading on similar SO questions, but couldn't figure out how to resolve my error.

I have written the following string of code:

```
points[paste0(score.avail,"_pts")] <- 
    Map('*', points[score.avail], mget(paste0(score.avail,'_m')) )
```

Essentially, I have a list of columns in the 'points' data frame, defined by 'score.avail'. I am multiplying each of the columns by a respective constant, defined as the `paste0(score.avail, '_m')` expression. It appends new fields based on the multiplication, given by `paste0(score.avail, "_pts")` expression.

I have used this function before in a similar setup with no issues. However, I am now getting the following error:

```
Error in .Primitive("*")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]]) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm pretty sure R is telling me that one of the fields I'm trying to multiply is not numeric. However, I have checked all my fields, and they are numeric. I have even tried running a line `as.numeric(score.avail)` but that doesn't help. I also ran the following to remove NA's in the fields (before the `Map` function above).

```
for(col in score.avail){
  points[is.na(get(col)) & (data.source == "average" | 
data.source ==  "averageWeighted"), (col) := 0]}
```

The thing that stumps me is that this expression has worked with no issues before.

**Update**

I did some more digging by separating out each component of my original function. I'm getting odd output when running `points[score.avail]`. Previously when I ran this, it would return just the columns for all of my rows. Now, however, I'm getting none of the rows in my original data frame -- rather, it is imputing the column names in the 'score.avail' list as rows and filling in NA's everywhere (this is clearly the source of my problem).

I think this is because I'm using the object I'm pointing to is a data.table with keyvars set. Previously with this function, I had been pointing to a data frame.

Off to try a few more things.

**Another Update**

I was able to solve my problem by copying the 'points' object using `as.data.frame()`. However, I will leave the question open to see if anyone knows how to reset the data table key vars so that the function I specified above will work.

Comment: What has changed since the expression last worked? New libraries loaded? Different machine and/or R installation? More details could be really helpful

Comment: It is better to show some example data using `dput`.  i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(points)))`  I tried the code on an example I created and it works well (assuming that the `points`  is `data.frame`.

Comment: Could be a bad/corrupted value somewhere in your data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by copying the 'points' object using as.data.frame(). Apparently classifying the object as a data.table was causing my headaches.